# Professional term for "Apples to apples" comparison

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, business-language

Is there a term which would sound more fitting in an academic or professional setting for describing a comparison between two things highlighting the similarity of the measurement/comparison process?

Comment: The comparison is *valid;* the things compared are *commensurable.*

Comment: Despite the vulgar saying to the contrary, it is perfectly reasonable to compare apples with oranges: both are round fruits of similar size and weight and color. An actual category error of comparing unlike things would be to compare apples to avarice, or oranges to orneriness. Apples and oranges are of the same category, and so are freely comparable.

Comment: >both are round fruits... There is always some category containing any two things or concepts. One might say that "apples" and "avarice" are both words. Commons sense and context should apply to the interpretation of language. Imho.

Comment: @Pam That is incorrect. *Category error* has a distinct meaning.  Apples and oranges belong to the same category. You can’t weasel-word out of the fact that apples and oranges are comparable whereas modulo metaphoric metanymy in the Garden of Eden, apples and avarice are not.

Comment: Well to me and many other people apple and oranges are "different" although they are both fruits. And in any case the meaning of the expression is pretty clear universally. Comparable respect to what ? Frankly, I don't see logical consistency in your line of reasoning.

Comment: @Pam Down that road of mass-popularity and confusion lies support for *could care less*, *last common denominator*, *irregardlessness*, and similar such meaningless nonsense. No thanks. Just because a lot of people talk nonsense doesn’t alter the nonsensical nature of such talk It doesn’t matter how many people think ᴨ is equal to ²²⁄₇: it’s still bogus, broken non-thinking; in a word, it’s still nonsense.

Comment: @tchrist I find it interesting that the "apples and oranges" phrase bothers you so much.  In my opinion, the similarity of the two items being juxtaposed is essential to the meaning of the statement.  One might successfully argue that apples and oranges have more traits in common than they have traits to differentiate them.  I believe this is the entire point of the phrase.  It is very tempting to compare apples and oranges as if they were the same thing, but the differences are significant enough that any useful comparison needs to take the differences into account.

Comment: @Pam - If "Apples and Avarice" was a book, I would read it cover to cover.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *like to like* is applicable to non-fruit applications.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *in comparable terms* may also work.